# How can I get all objects from Redis by mask or template quicklly?

Tags: database, redis, server-side

Good afternoon everyone, I want to get all objects from Redis by mask or template. I know that I can use KEYS, but it is very slow, because it works for O(n), where n is the size of all keys in the database, and returns only keys without data. Can you offer me a good solution?

Comment: Did you check RediSearch or RedisGears?

Answer (score 1):

You can use SCAN https://redis.io/commands/scan or HGETALL command and store your objects in a hash table for details, I advise you to look at the documentation https://redis.io/commands/hgetall.

Answer (score 0):

`SCAN` is the suitable option for replacement of `KEYS *` coz of time complexity. But you can't get the value of the key using this option. As you can use hash structure for this coz by using `HGETALL`you can retrieve all keys and values in a single call. These are the two options available for your case as @Qwe said. However I personally use bash script to get rid of these coz I don't want to change my structure to hash. Like this.,

```
#Default to '*' key pattern, meaning all redis keys in the namespace
REDIS_KEY_PATTERN="${REDIS_KEY_PATTERN:-*}"
for key in $(redis-cli --scan --pattern "$REDIS_KEY_PATTERN")

do
type=$(redis-cli type $key)
if [ $type = "list" ]
then
    printf "$key => \n$(redis-cli lrange $key 0 -1 | sed 's/^/  /')\n"
elif [ $type = "hash" ]
then
    printf "$key => \n$(redis-cli hgetall $key | sed 's/^/  /')\n"
else
    printf "$key => $(redis-cli get $key)\n"
fi
done
```

I hope this will be heplfull.